# SQL Selecting distinct data

Tags: sql

Let's say I have tables called Orders and OrdersInfo. Orders table looks like:

```
OrderID
1
2
3
```

And OrdersInfo

```
OrderID ProductID Amount
1       1         2
1       2         1
2       3         4
```

I'd like to get all information with the newest OrderID. 
In this case the answer should be an information of OrderID 3 which is gonna be empty. My problem is that I have to group it and my information does not show up properly.
I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT OI.OrderID, OI.ProductID, OI.Amount
FROM OrdersInfo OI
JOIN Orders O
ON OI.OrderID = O.OrderID
GROUP BY OI.OrderID, OI.ProductID, OI.Amount
HAVING OI.OrderID = MAX(O.OrderID)
```

Comment: @RyanVincent: That ID is sufficient if auto-incremented.

Comment: Well I have a procedure which increments ID. And I want table to be empty. ( Wanted to try this way without creating temp tables )

Comment: Show us what is your desire output.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I showed you. But since you can't write properly it's hard to understand what I want.

Comment: What part or desire output you dont understand?  You write `Orders` and `OrdersInfo`, but not the final result you expect. If you include current output and desire output we can detect what is wrong and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this-

```
SELECT
O.OrderID
,OI.ProductID
,OI.Amount

 FROM
(
SELECT
     MAX(OrderID) AS OrderID
FROM Orders
) AS O
LEFT JOIN OrdersInfo AS OI
OI.OrderID=O.OrderID
```

Answer (score -1):

USE `LEFT JOIN` and you will get NULLs for  `OrderID = 3`

```
SELECT TOP 1 O.OrderID, OI.ProductID, OI.Amount
FROM Orders O 
LEFT JOIN OrdersInfo OI
       ON OI.OrderID = O.OrderID
ORDER BY O.OrderId DESC
```

USE `TOP 1` for MSQL Server. `LIMIT 1` for postgresql

Comment: It's a bad code. you need to group by on what you select. And this code doesn't work

Comment: Even if this is a bad code, is rude you say it like that to someone trying to help you for free. Also you can include the error message so I can try to fix it.

Comment: It's better to be harsh than be soft on comments. People then take it more into account and try to do better next time ;).

Comment: Isnt the harsh part bother me, is the part where the comment isnt helpfull because doesnt include the error message. I udpate my answer with a simple solution, But because you didnt specify what is your rdbms not sure what limit use